# como leer un archivo txt con Java

Tags: java, archivo

Creo que necesito tambien un BufferedWriter y FileWriter pero no quiero escribir dentro del file solo quiero leerlo, modificar lo que ya esta leido y restuirlo dentro de un String

```
public String substituye(String parrafo) 
{
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        File file = Paths.get("desktop/pagina.html").toFile();
        String linea="";

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
        {   
            while(br.ready())
            {   
                linea = br.readLine();
                if(linea.equals("//inicio del parrafo de modificar"))
                    linea = parrafo;
                content.append(linea+"\n");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
```

// el problema es que modifica el archivo solo al inicio y no elimina el resto. Es decir, es como si hubiera eliminado el titutlo viejo del parrafo y en lugar de el puse el parrafo dentro della variable "parrafo" pero el cuerpo del resto del parrafo viejo sigue ahi

Comment: hola amigo, ya te publico la respuesta

Comment: yo hice algo similar

Comment: tambien necesitasbuscar algo dentro del archivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leer el contenido de un archivo por ejemplo un `.txt` te recomiendo que utilices `FileReader`, ejemplo:

```
File archivo = new File("ruta/del/archivo/a/leer/ejemplo.txt");
FileReader leer = new FileReader(archivo);
int a;

while ((a=leer.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.println((char)a);
}

leer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te he entendido bien.
Yo te diria que pruebes con el replace en vez del append. Aquí te dejo el enlace de la clase StringBuilder de Java:
[StringBuilder class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

> replace(int start, int end, String str)
>   Replaces the characters in a substring of this sequence with characters in the specified String.