# ¿Cómo guardo datos en un archivo para luego leerlos?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, formularios, ventana

necesito hacer una aplicación como proyecto final. Es una gestión de empleados con ventanas. Tiene 3 funciones principales: Insertar, Buscar y Modificar. Insertar consigo que lo haga (parcialmente), las otras 2 cosas no.
Así es como guardo los datos de la gente que inserto:

```
private void crearArchivo() {
    if (!archivo.exists()) {
        try {   //Si no existe, lo creo, pero si existe, escribiremos sobre el 
            archivo.createNewFile();
            escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);   //Esto es para escribir en el archivo
            line = new PrintWriter(escribir);
            //Escribimos en el archivo
            line.println("Nombre="+name.getText());
            line.println("Sueldo="+salary.getText());
            line.println("Sexo="+sexo.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            line.println("-----");
            //Además de imprimir en el txt para así mostrar después 
            escribir.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario insertado con éxito");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se ha producido un error");
        }
    } else {    //Aqui es lo que hace en caso de que exista
        try {   //Si no existe, lo creo, pero si existe, escribiremos sobre el 
            escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);   //Esto es para escribir en el archivo
            line = new PrintWriter(escribir);
            //Escribimos en el archivo
            line.println("Nombre="+name.getText());
            line.println("Sueldo="+salary.getText());
            line.println("Sexo="+sexo.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            line.println("-----");
            escribir.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario insertado con éxito");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Se ha producido un error");
        }
    }
}
```

Vale, eso me lo guarda en un txt que luego recupero, pero recupero los datos del último pese a que en el archivo están todos los que he metido. 
Mi forma de extraer esos datos es esta:

```
public void mostrarDatos() {
    if (archivo.exists()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
            Properties mostrar = new Properties();
            mostrar.load(fis);
            name.setText(mostrar.getProperty("Nombre"));
            salary.setText(mostrar.getProperty("Sueldo"));
            if ("Hombre".equals(mostrar.getProperty("Sexo"))) {
                datoSexo.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                datoSexo.setText(mostrar.getProperty("Sexo"));
            }

            if ("Mujer".equals(mostrar.getProperty("Sexo"))) {
                datoSexo.setForeground(Color.PINK);
                datoSexo.setText(mostrar.getProperty("Sexo"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Si supiera guardarla bien, podría buscar y modificar, pero con un txt no sé si es posible, alguna idea?
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina, por otra parte creo que puedes encontrar la respuesta en [Como leer un archivo txt con Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67750/). Saludos.

Comment: Necesitas tener en texto plano los trabajadores? podrías guardar diréctamente una lista de objetos de ese objeto en el fichero de este modo te sería mas fácil recuperarlo o modificarlo aunque tendrías que cambiar el como lo guardas